# Show Timer with MilliSeconds in a Label

Tags: objective-c

I need to record the time (with Milliseconds).
When button1 is clicked, timer will start.
When button2 is clicked, timer will stop.
I need to display the time interval (with milliseconds) in a label.
Sorry, I am new in IOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .h file of your class

```
@interface MyClass
{
    NSDate *_start;
}
```

When the first UILabel is clicked do this:

```
// start is an attribute of your class of type NSDate.
_start = [NSDate date];
```

And when the second button is clicked:

```
if (_start)
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [_start timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

`timeInterval` provide you the difference in millisecond between _start and now.

Comment: @pretty_girl Don't forget to click on the checked arrow to the left of my answer if its helped you.