# Displaying Game Time in Milliseconds Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, nstimer

So I am fooling around with some apps and I am trying to get a game timer to be in milliseconds instead of just the normal 1,2,3. I want it to be in a format similar to this 1.000,2.000. Or even 1.00,2.00.

Here is my code:

```
(void)startTimer {
    if (count == 30) {
      // 3
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                             target: self
                                           selector:@selector(ElapsedTime)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Where does `count` come from?

Comment: the counts coming from a label. The label is set to count down from 30 every time a button is pressed. I want to time it which is why i want a finer timer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457847/show-timer-with-milliseconds-in-a-label

Comment: this sounds like a dumb question but where would i put the start and end in my code.

Comment: You would put Duncan C's answer in `startTimer` at the beginning. Then you would update the label text by converting the time into a string, and then doing `[label setText:dateString]`

Answer (score 2):

Record the start time with

> NSTimeInterval start = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

Any time you want to see how much time has elapsed, use:

> NSTimeInterval elapsed = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] -
>   start;

`elapsed` will be in seconds. If you want milliseconds, subtract the whole number to get the decimal part. Multiply the decimal part by 1000 to get milliseconds.

If you want your time to change more often than once a second, make the time interval of your timer less than 1.0 seconds. Note that timers aren't accurate for more than about 1/50 of a second however.

Comment: It says that elapsed is an unused variable. Where would i put that?

Comment: alright dude. my b for askin. im new to xcode and c so im trying some stuff out. chill